# Line chart of D3.js won't show due to <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL38.695652173…"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web-development-server

I have this code that i'm working on and needed some help. The line chart won't show as it is.
Time in the x-axis of my line chart doesn't show the interval of 00:00:00 to 23:00:00. It just shows the 3am, 9am, 12pm, 3pm, 6pm, and 9pm and data also won't show on the y-axis. I was expecting that it will show 0,10,20...100 like in the picture below:
[image: Line chart]

But the error I'm getting is whenever i looked at the console:
`<path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL38.695652173…"`

I think this is what's making it a problem. But so far this is the only error I'm getting.
Can someone please help me..

This is the snippet of my code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");


    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.availability_time); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.total_hour_percentage); });

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("#lineChart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw(data) {
        console.log(data[0].availability_time);

        // format the data
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.availability_time = (parseTime(d.availability_time));
            d.total_hour_percentage = d.total_hour_percentage;
        });

        // sort time ascending
        data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a["availability_time"] - b["availability_time"];
        })

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.availability_time;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return Math.max(d.total_up_percentage);
        })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline);
        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    }
    // Get the data
    // var perHourResult = "/perHourAvailabilities/" + defaultDate;
    // console.log(perHourResult);

    var perHourResult = 
    [
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"00:00:00","total_hour_percentage":99.55},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"01:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"02:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"03:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"04:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"05:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"06:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"07:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"08:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"09:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"10:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"11:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"12:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"13:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"14:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"15:00:00","total_hour_percentage":99.75},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"16:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"17:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"18:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"19:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"20:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"21:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"22:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0},
        {"id":0,"availability_time":"23:00:00","total_hour_percentage":100.0}
    ];

    console.log(perHourResult[0].availability_time); //shows 00:00:00

    draw(perHourResult);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>

    <!--Lib css-->
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--fontawesome-->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--own css-->
    <style>
        @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

        body {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            background: #fafafa;
        }

        p {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.7em;
            color: #999;
        }

        a,
        a:hover,
        a:focus {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding: 15px 10px;
            background: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .navbar-btn {
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: none !important;
            border: none;
        }


        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: stretch;
        }

        #sidebar {
            min-width: 250px;
            max-width: 250px;
            background: rgb(60, 95, 238);
            color: #fff;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        #sidebar.active {
            margin-left: -250px;
        }

        #sidebar .sidebar-header {
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgb(90, 121, 243);
        }

        #sidebar ul.components {
            padding: 20px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
        }

        #sidebar ul p {
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            display: block;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #sidebar ul li.active>a,
        a[aria-expanded="true"] {
            color: #fff;
            background: #6d7fcc;
        }

        a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 20px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        ul ul a {
            font-size: 0.9em !important;
            padding-left: 30px !important;
            background: #6d7fcc;
        }

        ul.CTAs {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        ul.CTAs a {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.9em !important;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        a.download {
            background: #fff;
            color: #7386D5;
        }

        a.article,
        a.article:hover {
            background: #6d7fcc !important;
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

        #content {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            min-height: 100vh;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            #sidebar {
                margin-left: -250px;
            }

            #sidebar.active {
                margin-left: 0;
            }

            #sidebarCollapse span {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CHART STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- 

        /* LINE CHART STYLE */

        .axis--x path {
            display: none;
        }

        .line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
    </style>

    <!--lib js-->

    <!--bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--fontawesome js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

    <!--d3(chart) js-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="/">DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--End of nav.sidebar-->
        </nav>

        <!--Page content-->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!--End of div.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="lineChart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->
        </div>


    </div>
    <!--End of div.content-->

    </div>
    <!--End of div.wrapper-->

    <!--Lib <script>-->


    <!--own <script>-->

    <script src="js/script3.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We can see the y coordinates are undefined in the path data and error message, so there is probably an issue with the y scale or y accessor of the line. If you log `y.domain()` after you set it, you'll notice that it is `[0,undefined]`, that points us in the right direction. Where you set the domain you use `total_up_percentage`, which doesn't exist, but `total_hour_percentage` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain on the Y-axis was the core issue, replace your line with:

```
 y.domain([d3.min(data, d=>d.total_hour_percentage), d3.max(data, d=>d.total_hour_percentage)]);
```

For the x axis values, add the following to the axis section:

```
   // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.time).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%H:%M')));
```

For my working version, check out: https://jsfiddle.net/4op80hbz/1/

Comment: This worked! Perfectly fine! By the way, is there a way for the time in the x-axis to go by hours? For example 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 up to 23:00?

Comment: Add the: d3.timeHour.every(1) to the x-axis call *.call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeHour.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%H:%M')));*